# Acting only on text input in a KeyPress Event

Tags: c#, winforms, char, keypress

I have a key press event, and I want the combobox to handle the keypress if the input is not textual. I.E. If it is the up or down key, let the combobox handle it like it normally would, but if it's punctuation, or alphanumeric I want to act on it.

I thought **Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))** would do the trick, but it doesn't catch the arrow keys, and for a combobox, that's important.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I had from a previous answer I gave. It came from the MSDN documentation and I think you should be able to modify it nicely based on which characters you want to allow or disallow:

```
// Boolean flag used to determine when a character other than a number is entered.
private bool nonNumberEntered = false;

// Handle the KeyDown event to determine the type of character entered into the control.
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the flag to false.
    nonNumberEntered = false;

    // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
    {
        // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
        {
            // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
            if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
            {
                // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
                // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                nonNumberEntered = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) {
        nonNumberEntered = true;
    }
}

// This event occurs after the KeyDown event and can be used to prevent
// characters from entering the control.
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    if (nonNumberEntered == true)
    {
        // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Malfist: That's a good question and I don't know personally. The only other thing I could imagine you doing for international characters is to perform another check in there which would allow or disallow the ASCII/Unicode values you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check no textual characters.

I hope the following code helps :

```
void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        ...
    else if(Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        ...
}
```